# datetime related query in sql server

Tags: sql-server

```
DECLARE @PreviousMonthStart DATETIME
DECLARE @PreviousMonthEnd DATETIME

SET @PreviousMonthStart = DATEADD(m,DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())-1,0)
SET @PreviousMonthEnd = DATEADD(ms,-2,DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0))

PRINT @PreviousMonthStart
PRINT @PreviousMonthEnd
```

when executed above query the result set is in the below format

```
Mar  1 2017 12:00AM
Mar 31 2017 11:59PM
```

But I need result set in below format

```
2017-04-01 00:00:00.000
```

any help

Comment: They don't *have* a format whilst they're `datetime`s. It's only those `print`s that have to, for hopefully obvious reasons, transform them into *strings*. So long as you keep them as `datetime`s, they don't have formats and you don't have formatting issues.

Answer (score 0):

The result of the t-sql is what you want but because you are using `PRINT` to see the results it is casting the result into varchar before printing it.

If you simply do a select instead of the PRINT it will show you what you want to see.

```
DECLARE @PreviousMonthStart DATETIME
DECLARE @PreviousMonthEnd DATETIME

SET @PreviousMonthStart = DATEADD(m,DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())-1,0)
SET @PreviousMonthEnd = DATEADD(ms,-2,DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0))


SELECT @PreviousMonthStart      -- Result: 2017-03-01 00:00:00.000
SELECT @PreviousMonthEnd        -- Result: 2017-03-31 23:59:59.997

PRINT @PreviousMonthStart       -- Result: Mar  1 2017 12:00AM  
PRINT @PreviousMonthEnd         -- Result: Mar 31 2017 11:59PM
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `CONVERT` with the declared variable with the print statement.

```
DECLARE @PreviousMonthStart DATETIME
DECLARE @PreviousMonthEnd DATETIME

SET @PreviousMonthStart = DATEADD(m,DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())-1,0)
SET @PreviousMonthEnd = DATEADD(ms,-2,DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0))

PRINT CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),@PreviousMonthStart,120)
PRINT CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),@PreviousMonthEnd,120)
```

**Output:**

```
2017-03-01 00:00:00
2017-03-31 23:59:59
```